# GridSearchCV results are not reproducable

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, grid-search

Im new to Keras and I need your professional help.
I have used GridSearchCV to optmize my regression network. When i try to use the results, the newly created network is far worse in regards to the mean squared error than the one calculated by GridSearch.
The GridSearchCV code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from time import time
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV, cross_val_score
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error, mean_squared_error, r2_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler

from tensorflow import keras

from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping, TensorBoard
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten, Input, Dropout, LeakyReLU
from keras.utils import plot_model
from keras.optimizers import SGD, rmsprop, adam
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier, KerasRegressor
from keras.initializers import uniform, normal, glorot_uniform
from keras.losses import MAPE

#Data preprocessing

def get_data():
    data = pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep=";", usecols=["rHsubLS","b","lowerSetpoint"])
    test = data.loc[:,['rHsubLS','b']]
    target = data.loc[:,'lowerSetpoint']
    print(test.shape)
    print(target.shape)
    return test.astype(float), target.astype(float)

def split_data(test, target):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(test, target)
    X_train = np.array(X_train)
    X_test = np.array(X_test)
    y_train = np.array(y_train)
    y_test = np.array(y_test)

    stdsc1 = StandardScaler()
    train_data_std = stdsc1.fit_transform(X_train)
    test_data_std = stdsc1.fit_transform(X_test)

    y_train_1 = np.reshape(y_train, (-1, 1))
    y_test_1 = np.reshape(y_test, (-1, 1))
    train_target_std = stdsc1.fit_transform(y_train_1)
    test_target_std = stdsc1.fit_transform(y_test_1)

    return train_data_std, test_data_std, train_target_std, test_target_std

#Network Creation

def create_NN(optimizer='rmsprop', init='glorot_uniform', alpha=0.15, activation_func='tanh'):
    NN_model = Sequential()
    #input layer
    NN_model.add(Dense(128, kernel_initializer=init, input_dim=2, activation=activation_func))
    #hidden layers
    NN_model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=alpha))
    NN_model.add(Dense(256, kernel_initializer=init, activation='relu'))
    #output layer
    NN_model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer=init, activation='linear'))

    NN_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=["mse", "mape"])
    NN_model.summary()

    return NN_model

#GridSearchCV 

def train_NN(NN_model, train_data, train_target):
    seed = 4
    np.random.seed(seed)
    
    model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=create_NN, verbose=1)

    optimizers = ['rmsprop', 'adam', 'SGD']
    inits = ['glorot_uniform', 'normal', 'uniform', 'he_uniform']
    activation_funcs = ['tanh','relu','softmax']
    epochs = [50, 100, 150]
    batches = [50, 100, 500]
    alphas = [0.15, 0.45, 0.3]

    grid_parameter = dict(optimizer=optimizers, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batches, init=inits, alpha=alphas, activation_func=activation_funcs)#, dropout_rate=dropout)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error' , param_grid=grid_parameter, verbose=1, cv=3) 
        grid_results = grid.fit(train_data, train_target, use_multiprocessing=True, shuffle=True, workers=8) 
        print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_results.best_score_, grid_results.best_params_))
        means = grid_results.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
        stds = grid_results.cv_results_['std_test_score']
        params = grid_results.cv_results_['params']
        for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
            print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))


try:
    
        test, target = get_data()
        train_data, test_data, train_target, test_target = split_data(test, target)
        print("Data split\n")
        NN_model = create_NN()

        train_NN(NN_model, train_data, train_target)



except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    raise
```

The results of the GridSearch:

**Best: -0.000064 using {'activation_func': 'relu', 'alpha': 0.3, 'batch_size': 50, 'epochs': 150, 'init': 'he_uniform', 'optimizer': 'adam'}**

When I try to reproduce this network with this code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import time
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error, mean_squared_error
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler

from tensorflow import keras

from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping, TensorBoard
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten, Input, Dropout, PReLU, LeakyReLU
from keras.utils import plot_model
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.losses import MeanAbsolutePercentageError


def get_data():
    data = pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep=";", usecols=["rHsubLS","b","lowerSetpoint"])
    test = data.loc[:,['rHsubLS','b']]
    target = data.loc[:,'lowerSetpoint']
    print(test.shape)
    print(target.shape)
    return test.astype(float), target.astype(float)

def split_data(test, target):

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(test, target)
    X_train = np.array(X_train)
    X_test = np.array(X_test)
    y_train = np.array(y_train)
    y_test = np.array(y_test)

    stdsc1 = StandardScaler()
    train_data_std = stdsc1.fit_transform(X_train)
    test_data_std = stdsc1.fit_transform(X_test)
    y_train_1 = np.reshape(y_train, (-1, 1))
    y_test_1 = np.reshape(y_test, (-1, 1))
    train_target_std = stdsc1.fit_transform(y_train_1)
    test_target_std = stdsc1.fit_transform(y_test_1)

    return train_data_std, test_data_std, train_target_std, test_target_std

def create_NN():
    NN_model = Sequential()
    #input layer
    NN_model.add(Dense(128, input_dim=2, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', activation='relu'))
    #hidden layers
    NN_model.add(LeakyReLU(0.3))
    NN_model.add(Dense(256, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', activation='relu'))
    #output layer
    NN_model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

    keras.backend.set_epsilon(1)
    NN_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse','mape'])
    NN_model.summary()
    return NN_model

def train_NN(NN_model, train_data, train_target, test_data, test_target):
    history = NN_model.fit(train_data, train_target, epochs=150, shuffle=True, batch_size=50, verbose=1, use_multiprocessing=True)
    return history

def test_NN(NN_model, test_data, test_target, train_data, train_target):
    mean_test = NN_model.evaluate(test_data, test_target, verbose=1)
    mean_train = NN_model.evaluate(train_data, train_target, verbose=1)
    return mean_test, mean_train


try:
    seed = 4
    np.random.seed(seed)
    test, target = get_data()
    train_data, test_data, train_target, test_target = split_data(test, target)
    print("Data split\n")
    NN_model = create_NN()
    print("Neural Network created\n")
    history = train_NN(NN_model, train_data, train_target, test_data, test_target)
    mean_test, mean_train = test_NN(NN_model, test_data, test_target, train_data, train_target)
    print("Durchschnittliche Abweichung Training: ", mean_train)
    print("Durchschnittliche Abweichung Test: ", mean_test)
    print(NN_model.metrics_names)

    NN_model.save('Regelung_v1.h5')
    print("Neural Network saved")

except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    raise
```

I get this result:
**mse loss training data: 0.028168134637475015;
mse loss test data: 0.028960488473176955**

The mean average percentage error is at about 9%. This result is not what i expected.
Where is my mistake?

Thank you for your help in advance

Have a nice day!

PC Specs:

Intel i5 4570
16GB RAM + 16 GB page file
Nvidia GTX 1070
3 TB HDD

Software:

Windows 10
Geforce Game ready driver 451.48
Tensorflow 2.2.0
Keras 2.3.1
Sklearn 0.23.1
Cuda 10.1
Python 3.7.7

Edit: Here are a few lines of the test.csv

```
TIMESTAMP;rHsubLS;b;lowerSetpoint
20200714091423000.00000000000;2.28878288783;-0.74361743617;-0.27947195702
20200714091423000.00000000000;0.13274132741;-0.94552945529;-0.32351276857
20200714091423000.00000000000;1.85753857539;0.77844778448;0.22244954249
20200714091423000.00000000000;1.31896318963;0.44518445184;0.33573301999
20200714091423000.00000000000;2.55885558856;-0.77792777928;-0.28837806344
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow. You will get helped quicker if you try to strip your code down to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You maybe also want to embed the data loaded from `test.csv` in your example.

Answer (score 0):

The Output layer had its initialization weight missing:

NN_model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', activation='linear'))